# Add multiple values of a book to an ArrayList in java

Tags: java, methods, arraylist

i am slightly confused on how to add in multiple values into an array list.

What im trying to do is to add multiple values of 1 object into an array list.

**For Example:**

I have an array list called books and im trying to add a book with its title, author, year published and so on...

Here is where i have given it a try but i am not sure if its right or if there is an easier way.

```
public class Book {

    public static ArrayList<Book> Books = new ArrayList<>();

    public int isbn;
    public int yearPublished;
    public String title;
    public String author;
    public String price;
    public int noOfCopies;

  Book b1 = new Book(1234, 1991, "Book1", "mark.mark", "£11.00", 5);
  Book b2 = new Book(4321, 1994, "Book2", "bob.bob", "£12.00", 3);



    public Book(int ISBN, int year, String ttle, String auth, String pri, int copies) {

        this.isbn = ISBN;
        this.yearPublished = year;
        this.title = ttle;
        this.author = auth;
        this.price = pri;
        this.noOfCopies = copies;

        Books.add(this);
    }
}
```

Is this right? could anyone help me please

Comment: Are you getting a StackOverflowError?

Comment: You should respect naming convention. With `Books.add(this);`, we have the impression that `add` is a static method of the class `Books`.

Comment: Remove definitions of **b1** and **b2**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to arrange your code:

```
// Class Definition
public class Book {
    // Member Variables
    public int isbn;
    public int yearPublished;
    public String title;
    public String author;
    public String price;
    public int noOfCopies;

    // Constructor
    public Book(int ISBN, int year, String ttle, String auth, String pri, int copies) {

        this.isbn = ISBN;
        this.yearPublished = year;
        this.title = ttle;
        this.author = auth;
        this.price = pri;
        this.noOfCopies = copies;
    }

    // Create a List of Books
    public static List<Book> getBooks() {
        Book b1 = new Book(1234, 1991, "Book1", "mark.mark", "£11.00", 5);
        Book b2 = new Book(4321, 1994, "Book2", "bob.bob", "£12.00", 3);
        List<Book> books = new ArrayList<Book>();
        books.add(b1);
        books.add(b2);
        return books;
    }
}
```

And after that, you can get your example books by calling getBooks() function:

```
List<Book> exampleBooks = Book.getBooks();
```

Answer (score 2):

This `public static ArrayList<Book> Books = new ArrayList<>();` can't be in the Book class. Instead you should make some kind of container class, for example `public class BookShelf`, which will be agregating books in this array of Books.

Another bad thing is that you are making application logic in POJO class. Statements like `Book b1 = new Book...` should be in method in your runtime class, not in POJO. And POJO's should contain only private members with getters/setters, and eventually toString method.

Also, avoid creating public members. They should be private with getters and setters.

Answer (score 2):

The list of books should be managed in a separate class from `Book`. For example, you might have

```
public class Library
{
    private ArrayList<Book> books = new ArrayList<Book>();

    public Library()
    {
        Book b1 = new Book(...);
        Book b2 = new Book(...);

        books.add(b1);
        books.add(b2);
    }
}

public class Book
{
    private int isbn;
    private int yearPublished;
    private String title;
    private String author;
    private String price;
    private int noOfCopies;

    public Book(int ISBN, int year, String ttle, String auth, String pri, int copies)
    {
        this.isbn = ISBN;
        this.yearPublished = year;
        this.title = ttle;
        this.author = auth;
        this.price = pri;
        this.noOfCopies = copies;
    }

    // getter and setter for each field
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the help! This and the answer above helps :)

Answer (score 1):

The cause of whatever errors you are seeing right now is the instance variable

```
Book b1 = new Book(1234, 1991, "Book1", "mark.mark", "£11.00", 5);
```

For each `Book` instance you create, it will create a `Book` instance which will create a `Book` instance, which will create a `Book` instance, ad nauseam, eventually causing a `StackOverflowError`.

Remove those `b1` and `b2` and create them outside the class from a driver program.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest not creating a books object within the book class (a book doesn't contain books. It makes no sence). I suggest moving books to its own class.

Doing so, you have:
Books books = new Books();
Book book1 = new Book();
Book book2 = new Book();
books.add(book1);
books.add(book2);